# Github project in intellij idea with vaadin, liferay + tomcat

Tags: tomcat, github, intellij-idea, liferay, vaadin

A little background: I am mathematics and biology student and i know only hard programming.

I have to setup https://github.com/qbicsoftware with `vaadin` support and a `liferay` + *apache tomcat bundle*. No one who knows about this is in the office. I decided to use intellij idea ultimate, because someone told me to.

So far I have download the project, intellij idea, vaadin, liferay + apache tomcat.
I got the basic instruction to

1. deploy the (module) project as a `.war` file in intellij idea, but so far I think I could not setup the `liferay` bundle and `vaadin` support in intellij idea.
2. copy `.war` file in deploy folder of `liferay` and open local address in browser.

Can anyone help me a little on one of those tasks or both?

Comment: have a look https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integrating+Vaadin+7+with+Liferay

Comment: Ok, tried that, but there is no vaadin-shared-deps.jar anymore. Maybe it is now named vaadin-shared?